# How do you pass a prop inside a function inside a template in vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to pass a prop inside a function inside a template for a to-do test site I'm making. Basically I want to have a list item which includes the todo item with a button next to it that deletes the same item.

```
Vue.component("todo-item", {
          props: ["todotext"],
          template: "<li>{{todotext.text}} <button v-on:click='removeThisItem({{todotext}})'>X</button></li>",
        })

        var next_id = 3

        var app = new Vue ({
          el: "#app",
          data: {
            message: "",
            todos: [
              {id: 0, text: "Do assignment"},
            ]
          },
          methods: {
            addTodoItem: function () {
              this.todos.push({id: next_id, text: this.message})
              next_id += 1
            },

            removeThisItem: function removeThisItem (item) {
              this.todos.splice(this.todos.indexOf(item))
            }
          }
        })
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="app">
        <input type="text" name="" v-model="message">
        <button type="button" name="button" v-on:click="addTodoItem">Add Todo Item</button>
        <ul>
          <todo-item
            v-for="todo in todos"
            v-bind:todotext="todo"
            v-bind:key="todo.id">
          </todo-item>

        </ul>
      </div>
```

However I get the error
`invalid expression: Unexpected token '{' in removeThisItem({{todotext}})`
Is there a way to pass the prop as an argument inside this function inside this template to be able to delete this list item?

Edit: Here is the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/f6sn52w8/

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the curly braces, just with  `<button v-on:click='removeThisItem(todotext)'>X</button>` it should work, I don't understand the use case very well, if you give us a jsfiddle or codesandbox with your code, maybe we can help you properly. Remember, when you are using `on:click` the part after the `=` sign is handled as javascript, so {{todotext}} in Javascript doesn't have sense, that't why you must pass the variable that you want to use.

Comment: @AndresForonda Hey thanks, I tried that and it doesn't seem to work. It just says that removeThisItem is not a function. I made a JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f6sn52w8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, trying to solve the issue in your jsfiddle I got the error

`[Vue warn]: Property or method "outerHTML" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.  (found in <TodoItem>)`

Anyway, I figure it out what is happening with your code and why it isn't working.

You have the parent component where you are using your `todo-item` component:

```
<!-- parent component -->
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="" v-model="message">
  <button type="button" name="button" v-on:click="addTodoItem">
    Add Todo Item
  </button>
    <ul>
      <todo-item
        v-for="todo in todos"
        v-bind:todotext="todo"
        v-bind:key="todo.id">
      </todo-item>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

The method removeThisItem is declared in this component, so it isn't available in the child component `<todo-item>`, that's why you see the error in the console.

So the way to handle the click to remove the item is by listening for an event in the parent component and emitting the event from the child component:

Note about shorthand: `v-bind:todotext="todo"` is the same as `:todotext="todo"`, and `v-on:click` is the same as `@click`

```
<!-- parent component -->
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" name="" v-model="message">
  <button type="button" name="button" v-on:click="addTodoItem">
    Add Todo Item
  </button>
    <ul>
      <todo-item
        v-for="todo in todos"
        :todotext="todo"
        :key="todo.id"
        @removeItem="removeThisItem"> <!-- listen for the removeItem event and run the removeThisItem method when it's triggered -->
      </todo-item>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Now the child component template must be updated:

```
Vue.component("todo-item", {
  props: ["todotext"],
  template:
    `<li>
       {{todotext.text}} 
       <button @click="$emit('removeItem', todotext)">X</button>
    </li>`,
})
```

The `todo-item` component will emit the event `removeItem` when the button is clicked, and will send `todotext` prop as parameter to the function that will run on the parent (removeThisItem).

An alternative way to explain better this behavior:

```
Vue.component("todo-item", {
  props: ["todotext"],
  template:
    `<li>
       {{todotext.text}} 
       <button @click="emitEventRemoveItem">X</button>
     </li>`,
   methods: {
    emitEventRemoveItem() {
      // this.$emit will emit an event to the parent
      // the first parameter is the event name, the second parameter
      // is the argument that is expected in the parent method that
      // will run when the event is triggered, removeThisItem in this case
      this.$emit('removeItem', this.todotext);
    }
   }
})
```

Try to run this in your editor, in jsfiddle I got an error. Anyway, the issue is that you're trying to run a method that is declared in the parent component from the child component.

Let me know if it works or if you get any error.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot! I put what you said in JSFiddle and now I understand completely what you mentioned intuitively, however while now there is no error what I try and delete the todo item, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you run the code locally in your code editor?, honestly I like to create my projects using Vue CLI and have the folder structure to import .vue components, using Vue.component is not my strength, anyway, test your code locally (not in jsfiddle) and let me know if something changes.